# Clarity over Python and Jython

Tags: java, python

I'm a Java programmer, but I want to program in Jython. I've never coded in Python before, but have been looking through some tutorials and I'm fairly confident I can grasp it.

My question is clarity over Jython. I understand with Jython you have the joys of writing Python code with the added bonus of accessing Java libraries. Does this mean, all aspects and coding practices of Python can be applied, such as creating animation, input out structures, or is there a whole new structure which needs to be learned to code Jython?

Comment: jython is just an implementation of the Python language written in Java, capable of accessing Java libraries.  The language itself doesn't change significantly, AFAIK.

Comment: You do want to focus on *one* question at a time; remove the external resource request (software for realtime animation); such questions are off-topic.

Comment: Tangential, you may wish to consider other jvm languages that are designed to work with the jvm (clojure, scala, groovy to name a few) instead of another language that is contorted to fit the jvm - though that gets to be optioning and best for a discussion in chat. R

Comment: How is Python contorted to fit the JVM? Especially considering that Python is older than the JVM?

Comment: @JörgWMittag there are design decisions as part of [Python language reference](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/) such that jython has tried to keep close, but has diverged in some areas. These range from minor string formats to functions not existing (for example, `fork()`). Writing jython gives you the JRE, but that code becomes completely incompatible with mainstream python when taking advantage of the JRE. There are other languages that have wider (and more practical) adoption than jython if one wants to remain in the jvm. Though admittedly, this is getting into the realm of discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jython is Python implemented in Java.  Unfortunately, if you want the latest and greatest, you won't get it.  The Jython implementation is several versions behind, so some newer features are not available.

As you noted, you can import from Java libraries and use the features you want from Java.

Coding style is radically different from Java.  Indentation is important, as is choice of tabs or spaces for indentation.

Variable usage and typing is also significantly different.  Variables are not declared, but must be assigned before use.

The ability to prototype at the command line is a great feature.

The static code analysis you are used to in Java is not a feature of the language.  Some IDEs do provide the some checks, and can save debugging time.

Any real-time animation will have the same issues with garbage collection that a Java program would have.

Comment: if its several versions behind, what disadvantages does this have? What are the limitations? I want to program this interface system which provides information, i wanted to use python, for simplicity of code but still have access to swing and awt.

Comment: @F.Dot From the Java standpoint it makes no difference.  From the Python standpoint, newer features of Python will not be available.  When searching documentation, stick to the 2.x documentation.  The current stable version of Jython is 2.5.3, and you won't have features newer than that.  Documentation generally indicates which version a feature was first available in.

Answer (score 0):

Jython is an implementation of Python, just like OpenJDK is an implementation of Java. And just like with Java, it doesn't matter which implementation you use (provided that you don't use any implementation-specific features, obviously).

Comment: implementation specific features?

Comment: For example, CPython allows you to extend the interpreter with modules written in C and Jython allows you to extend the interpreter with modules written in Java. Obviously, libraries which are written partly in C won't work in Jython and libraries which are written partly in Java won't work in CPython. Again, this is just like in Java: J9 performs tail-call optimization, HotSpot doesn't. If you rely on TCO, your code will work on J9 but not on HotSpot.

Comment: Garbage Collection is another example: CPython uses a reference counting collector in conjunction with a simple mark-and-sweep tracing collector. Which means that as long as you don't have cycles, you will have deterministic finalization on CPython. However, there is nothing in the language specification which guarantees this, and it only works by accident on CPython. It won't work on Jython, IronPython, PyPy, Pynie, or any other Python implementation.

Comment: if its several versions behind, what disadvantages does this have? What are the limitations? I want to program this interface system which provides information, i wanted to use python, for simplicity of code but still have access to swing and awt